# How to turn a coordinate array used for making a standard google maps v3 polygon into a format that can be encoded?

Tags: google-maps, maps, polygon, encode

I have arrays formatted like this one in a database that I use for drawing polygons. This works fine.

```
[{lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}, {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118}, {lat: 32.321, Lng: -64.757}]
```

I have access to these arrays as strings in my JavaScript code.

I would now like to use the google.maps.geometry.encoding.encodePath to make encoded strings out of these for faster drawing of the polygons.

Any suggestions? Best Regards / Henke